# Become operator on all channels ircd-hybrid

Tags: ubuntu, irc, ircd

I have a problem with my `ircd-hybrid` server. I can only make myself operator in the status tab but not when I join channels.

There is my operator tag in `ircd.conf`:

```
operator {
    /* name: the name of the oper */
    name = "operator";

    /* user: the user@host required for this operator.  CIDR is not
     * supported.  multiple user="" lines are supported.
     */
    user = "*@127.0.0.1";

    /* password: the password required to oper.  By default this will
     * need to be encrypted using '/usr/bin/mkpasswd'.
     * WARNING: Please do not mix up the 'mkpasswd' program from 
     * /usr/sbin with this one. If you are root, typing 'mkpasswd' 
     * will run that one instead and you will receive a strange error.
     *
     * MD5 is supported. If you want to use it, use mkpasswd -Hmd5.
     */
    #password = "3ZokNTld506nY";
    password = "$1$oqD3q/0S$wQ1utcJG9Pcutmq6i3qxS.";

    /* class: the class the oper joins when they successfully /oper */
    class = "opers";

    /* privileges: controls the activities and commands an oper are 
     * allowed to do on the server.  All options default to no.
     * Available options:
     *
     * global_kill:  allows remote users to be /KILL'd (OLD 'O' flag)
     * remote:       allows remote SQUIT and CONNECT   (OLD 'R' flag)
     * kline:        allows KILL, KLINE and DLINE      (OLD 'K' flag)
     * unkline:      allows UNKLINE and UNDLINE        (OLD 'U' flag)
     * gline:        allows GLINE                      (OLD 'G' flag)
     * nick_changes: allows oper to see nickchanges    (OLD 'N' flag)
     *               via usermode +n
     * rehash:       allows oper to REHASH config      (OLD 'H' flag)
     * die:          allows DIE and RESTART            (OLD 'D' flag)
     * admin:        gives admin privileges.  admins
     *               may (un)load modules and see the
     *               real IPs of servers.
     */
    global_kill = yes;
    remote = yes;
    kline = yes;
    unkline = yes;
    gline = yes;
    die = yes;
    rehash = yes;
    nick_changes = yes;
    admin = yes;
};
```

Also, how can I configure the server so that when a user joins a channel first, they do not become an operator for the channel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- connect to your IRC server.
- get operator rights:

  - /oper operator
  - enter your password
  - IRC server show text "You have entered... the Twilight Zone!"
- /quote MODLOAD m_opme.so

  - this load module "OPME" on server
- /quote opme #channel

  - now you have operator rights in #channel

Comment: MODLOAD seems to be deprecated:
o) Replaced MODLOAD, MODUNLOAD, MODRELOAD, MODLIST and MODRESTART commands with the new MODULE command which can be fed with the LOAD, UNLOAD, RELOAD and LIST parameters. MODRESTART has been entirely removed. Use "MODULE RELOAD*" to reload all modules.

sauce: https://github.com/jmaurice/ircd-hybrid/blob/master/NEWS

Answer (score 0):

The ircd-hybrid package in Debian Jessie (and possibly Ubuntu) doesn't contain the opme module.

The version in Debian Stretch does, but in /usr/lib/ircd-hybrid/modules/extra . You should add this path in the modules section of ircd.conf .

You should also add the opme flag in the operator section of ircd.conf , and reload/restart the daemon.

Then you will be able to do

```
/oper yourusername yourpassword
/quote MODULE LOAD m_opme.la
/quote opme #channel
```